# Add calculated value to OData result

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api-odata, odata-v4

I'm trying to add some info to the data result whether the user has read or write access to the entity.

Lets assume I have this entity:

```
public class Foo
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Access> AccessRights { get; set; }
}
```

Where `AccessRights` holds the user id and if they have read/write access.

Currently I just `$expand` AccessRights and calculate if the user has read/write access in the frontend. However I'd like this calculated property to be added to the result.

Example json result:

```
{
   id: 1,
   name: "foo",
   hasReadAccess: true,
   hasWriteAccess: true
}
```

Is it possible to do this? Keep in mind that `HasRead/WriteAccess` doesn't exist on the model nor should it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split your model in two: a data access model (what you get from the data access layer) and a data transfer model (what you send as a response).

Assuming your current `Foo` class as the data access model, you simply need to define another class `FooResponse` (or whatever name suits you) as follows.

```
public class FooResponse
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool HasReadAccess { get; set; }
    public bool HasWriteAccess { get; set; }
}
```

Then define a *transformation* function that maps from `Foo` instances to `FooResponse` instances. [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) is a good tool for the job.

Comment: That's how I usually do it. But I can't see how DTOs will play nice with OData controllers.

Comment: Why would it matter? The DTO is simply the entity type that the controller handles.

Comment: Because the OData controller directly interacts with your repostory. That way you're able to filter and sort via the URL.

Comment: Hmm. I had assumed that you could add an `ODataQueryOptions` parameter to an action method that returns `IHttpActionResult` and then handle the query options inside the method using `ODataQueryOptions.ApplyTo`, but I see now that does not work.